# Serialization of ArgumentNullException to Json

Tags: c#, json.net, argumentnullexception

When serializing a `System.ArgumentNullException` to JSON using JSON.NET, part of the message appears lost:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ArgumentNullException("argument", "Some Message"));
```

returns:

```
{
"ClassName":"System.ArgumentNullException",
"Message":"Some Message",
"Data":null,
"InnerException":null,
"HelpURL":null,
"StackTraceString":null,
"RemoteStackTraceString":null,
"RemoteStackIndex":0,
"ExceptionMethod":null,
"HResult":-2147467261,
"Source":null,
"WatsonBuckets":null
}
```

I expected the Message token to be:

```
"Some Message\r\nParameter name: argument"
```

As noted by codefuller, the `ArgumentNullException` implements `ISerializable` and is the culprit. I can disable this by using custom `JsonSerializerSettings`.

However, the application needs to serialize any objects, including objects with an `ArgumentNullException` property. I'd prefer to **avoid** ignoring `ISerialiable` unless it presents a problem.

Both of my solutions include a custom `JsonConverter`.

**Solution 1: Centralized JsonSerializer**

- Create a static list of `JsonConverters` to add to `JsonSerializer.Converters`
- Include an `ExceptionConverter` that handles `ArgumentNullException` explicitly
- Everywhere I need to serialize, ensure my `JsonSerializer` includes these converters

Cons: other developers must rigorously ensure they are including these converters with any serialization they do.

**Solution 2: Override ArgumentNullException**

I can create a `CustomArgumentNullException` class, and tag it with a `JsonConvert` attribute to leverage my custom converter.

Cons: other developers must rigorously ensure they are raising a `CustomArgumentNullException` instead of an `ArgumentNullExcpetion`.

**Wished-for Solution**

I'd love to somehow tag the existing `ArgumentNullException` with a `JsonConverter` attribute pointing to my custom converter. Is there some way to achieve this in the Json.NET code base?

Comment: I can work around the issue by creating a custom JsonConverter for the ArgumentNullException class, and explicitly adding it to a JsonSerializer, but this seems ... ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Exception classes implement `ISerializable` interface. By the default for such objects Json.Net uses `ISerializable.GetObjectData()` method for data serialization. In other words `ArgumentNullException` class controls by itself how its data will be serialized. And somewhere inside it has a logic that serializes only actual message that was passed to constructor without `Parameter name: argument` part.

You could change this Json.Net behavior and avoid using of `GetObjectData()` with following `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
    {
        IgnoreSerializableInterface = true,
    },
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ArgumentNullException("argument", "Some Message"), settings);
```

However in this case set of serialized fields will differ from original json. Check whether it actually suits your needs.

Comment: Yes, that gives me a reasonable serialization. However, my challenge is a bit broader than my question poses: what is a reasonable way to apply that throughout an application stack when serializing objects that may include an ArgumentNullException property? I'll edit the question appropriately. Thanks!